# C# 7Zip zip file created but empty

Tags: c#, compression, 7zip

I am using following c# code to create a `.zip` file.

```
        string targetName = "E\\BACKUP\\BillGST.zip"; 
        ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
        p.FileName = "7Zip.exe";
        p.Arguments = "a " + targetName + " " + "E:\\BillGST.mdf " + "E:\\BillGST_log.ldf";
        p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process x = Process.Start(p);
        x.WaitForExit();
```

Process get completed successfully and `BillGST.zip` created at `E:\\BACKUP` but zip file is empty, nothing in it.

May i know why?

**UPDATE**

Error while taking backup via tsql

[image]

**Solution**

Used `backup database "e:\backup.mdf" to disk='e:\backup\backup.bak'`

Double quotes is the key

Comment: Comment out the hidden window style setting, check the exit code, capture the output of 7zip, what have you tried?

Comment: Ok wait a second

Comment: Also, why aren't you creating the backup using T-SQL instead? Did you detach that database before backing it up?

Comment: How do i take backup of sqllocaldb database via tsql?

Comment: `backup database 'E:\billgst.mdf' to disk 'E:\backup\billgst.zip'` giving me error

Comment: That's too bad but unless you post the error nobody here can help. Is `E:` available for the SQL Server? Is it a mapped drive?

Comment: Yes its a local drive just like a C drive and its available.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen please see updated question with error image